# Generating a new string from an array each time a function is called using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a new word each time the difficultyEasy function runs, the function randomisePosition basically is choosing one of the p tags in my HTML which displays words in different places.
I need it choose a different p tag each time difficultyEasy runs

the question is, how do I have the randomisePosition function not choose the same index in the array when i call the function

HTML 
```

```
<div class="ag-tetris">
        <p id="anagram1"></p>
        <p id="anagram2"></p>
        <p id="anagram3"></p>
        <p id="anagram4"></p>
        <p id="anagram5"></p>
        <p id="anagram6"></p>
        <p id="anagram7"></p>
        <p id="anagram8"></p>
        <p id="anagram9"></p>
        <p id="anagram10"></p>
      </div>``
```

Javascript (jQuery) -

```
console.log('JS Loaded');
$(() => {
  let interval;
  const $playGame = $('#play');
  const $inputByUser = $('#answer');
  const $subjectOptions = $('#subject-options');
  const $difficultyOptions = $('#difficulty-options');
  const $anagram1 = $('#anagram1');
  const $anagram2 = $('#anagram2');
  const $anagram3 = $('#anagram3');
  const $anagram4 = $('#anagram4');
  const $anagram5 = $('#anagram5');
  const $anagram6 = $('#anagram6');
  const $anagram7 = $('#anagram7');
  const $anagram8 = $('#anagram8');
  const $anagram9 = $('#anagram9');
  const $anagram10 = $('#anagram10');
  const $anagrams = [$anagram1, $anagram2,$anagram3,$anagram4,$anagram5,$anagram6,$anagram7,$anagram8,$anagram9,$anagram10];
  const categories = {
    BBT: ['sheldon','leanord','spock','cheesecakefactory','howard','startrek','penny','koothrapoli','bernadette','physics','laundry','halonight','dumplings', 'brisket','nasa','stringtheory','darkmatter', 'comiccon','comicbook'],
    LOTR: ['arragon', 'gimli']
  }
  ////////////////////Selectors///////////////////////////
  let selectedDifficulty = '';
  let selectedSubject = '';
  $subjectOptions.on('change', () => {
    const value = $subjectOptions.val();
    selectedSubject = categories[value];
  });
  $difficultyOptions.on('change', () => {
    selectedDifficulty = $difficultyOptions.val();
  });
  ////////////////////Selectors///////////////////////////
  /// Selects a random position (p -tag from the DOM) and stores it inside selectedAnagram
  function generateWord() {
    const selectedWord = selectedSubject[Math.floor(Math.random() * selectedSubject.length)];
    return selectedWord;
  }
  function generateAnagram(selectedWord) {
    return selectedWord.split('').sort(function(){
      return 0.5 - Math.random();
    } ).join('');
  }
  function randomisePosition () {
    $anagrams[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)];
  }
  function difficultyEasy (selectedAnagram){
    const selectedAnagram = randomisePosition();
    const selectedWord = generateWord();
    const scrambledWord = generateAnagram(selectedWord);
    selectedAnagram.text(scrambledWord);
    selectedAnagram.attr('data-word', selectedWord);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      selectedAnagram.css('top', '+=10px');
    },2000);
  }
  //current score of the player
  let lifeScore = 5;
  let currentScore = 0;
  //code validation of anagram
  /// function that stops and animates a correctly guesses answer
  //////////////////////////WORKING CODE//////////////////////////////////////
  $('#submit').on('click', function () {
    const selectedWord = selectedAnagram.attr('data-word');
    if($('#answer').val() === selectedWord){
      selectedAnagram.text(selectedWord).css('display','hidden');
      console.log(currentScore = currentScore + selectedWord.length);
      selectedAnagram.addClass('animated fadeOutLeft').css('color','green');
    } else {
      selectedAnagram.addClass('animated wobble').css('color','red');
      //This needs to be applied when a word gets to a certain point// console.log( lifeScore = lifeScore -1);
    }
  }
);
$playGame.on('click', function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    difficultyEasy(selectedAnagram);
  },2000);
});
```

Comment: Ok, what's the question? Is it working? If not, how not? Any errors?

Comment: apologies, it's changing the word for every interval when I'm calling the `difficultyEasy` function each time and it is staying with the same selected `#anagram`

Comment: You stated your objective but not what the specific problem or question is. Take some time to read through [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: return statement missing in randomisePosition function

Comment: the question is, how do I have the `randomisePosition` function not choose the same index in the array when i call the function

Comment: @VikramSingh's comment answers that question. Your `randomisePosition` function currently does nothing and returns `undefined`. I'm pretty sure you should be getting an error when you get to the line `selectedAnagram.text(scrambledWord);`. If you are not, then you're not showing the correct code.

Comment: apologies, this is the updated code ...

Comment: `let selectedAnagram = '';
  function randomisePosition () {
 selectedAnagram = $anagrams[Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)];
    return selectedAnagram;
  }`